# IntelliJ IDEA global environment variable configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, intellij-plugin

I need to use an environment variable in all of my idea run configurations. I currently use **run**->**edit configurations**->**and then enter the env variables in selected configuration**. However, that's very tedious when I need to run isolated test scenarios because each one creates a new run configuration and I need to enter the variables all over again.

I tried to set the env variables in my linux system using `export SOME_VAR="some value"` in various session profile files: `/etc/profile`,`/etc/bash.bashrc`,`~/.bashrc`,`~/.profile` but IntelliJ seems to ignore those vars during run, even though when I launch `echo ${SOME_VAR}` from IntelliJ built-in terminal it displays the correct output.

I also tried using [IntelliJ .env file plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-env-file) and then set `SOME_VAR=some value` in `.env` file in project root. Didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try editing the configuration under the `Default` node so that this setting automatically applies to all the new Run/Debug configurations of this type you create later?

Comment: I've noticed that IntelliJ honors the `/etc/environment` configuration file...

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589 regarding what environment IntelliJ IDEA can load on Linux.

Comment: I know it is old question, but in case your env variables are secrets stored in a seperate key management tool like Hashicorp Vault, and you dont want to duplicate them in a local .env file, see my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77335858/1594088

Answer (score 21):

In my opinion the real issue is what Mat said.
If you want to launch IntelliJ from a shortcut, then you have to edit it a little bit:
Open the .desktop file, and add `/bin/bash -c -i` to the beginning of the launch command. The file should look something like this:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/bin/bash -i -c "/path/to/idea/bin/idea.sh" %f
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

Update:

As @sherminator35 comments the desktop file in ubuntu is located at `.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`

Comment: This was the easiest solution that worked for me. In my case it was for Goland:
Exec=bash -i -c "/home/flapjack/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Goland/ch-0/202.6948.9/bin/goland.sh" %f

Comment: That should be the most voted answer... It's easy and works

Comment: Yes, this answer should be most voted. For Ubuntu 18.04 and IntelliJ 2020.3, the .desktop file is at `.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`

Answer (score 17):

I found a solution to set environment variables on IntelliJ that has been working very well for me, and is incredibly simple. Let me show you.

This is the program (you can copy and paste it) we're using to test:

```java
package com.javasd.intelijenv;

import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
        }

        System.out.println("My home directory: " + System.getenv("MY_VAR"));
    }
}
```

This program basically loads all environment variables, show them on the console, and try to show an env variable. Also, it assumes that you had created the **MY_VAR** env variable **before calling IntelliJ IDEA**, by doing something like:

```bash
$ export MY_VAR="This is my adorable var :)"
$ idea
```

*Please, notice that we're calling IntelliJ IDEA in the same terminal (or session, or window) where we created the environment variable. If you create the variable and call the IDEA from the icon, the solution won't work because the IDEA will create its own session.*

So, if run it without the correct configuration you will get something line this in your console:

[image]

Please, notice that you have just a few variables, and that MY_VAR is null.

### Here's configuration I use to load the environment variables:

1. Click on the "Select Run/Debug Configurations" in your project and select "Edit Configurations":

[image]

2. Then, click on the the button with "..." on the right side of the "Environment Variables" section:

[image]

3. You'll see a pop-up. Check the checkbox on the bottom-left which has the label "Include parent environment variables":

[image]

**That's it!!!**

If you run your program now you will see something like this on your console:

[image]

You can see all the environment variables and, of course, your "MY_VAR" variable, with the right value!

### Beyond the Basics

Usually, for security reasons, we don't want to keep all the environment variables visible. What we want to do is to make those variables visible only while the IntelliJ (or our program) is running.

So, no sensitive variables should be visible on the environment neither before you call Intellij nor after you close it.

Also, you want to keep those variables in a file (typically with a .env extension) to make it easy to manipulate and for security reasons.

To achieve this, there are some useful programs (you can Google them), but my favorite one is the [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd).

Let's say you have a **test.env** file with the following content:

```
MY_TEST_VAR=I live in the test.env file.
```

If you call IntelliJ by doing this:

```bash
$ env-cmd test.env idea
```

And edit your program to show "MY_TEST_VAR", and run it, you will see this on the IntelliJ's console:

[image]

But if you quit the IntelliJ, and look for your variable, you will see that the var doesn't exist (you can use `env` to confirm):

[image]

At this point, I hope you're able to play with your own solutions: create shell scripts with variables set inside, test other programs ([direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv), [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv), etc.), and so on.

Comment: The Run Configuration you show here is specific to the application main class, but the OP said he is not talking about a main class but about a large number of unit test methods. Each of these will create a new, separate run configuration.

Comment: Like explained in previous comment, this does not answer to the question asked. Luckily some of the other answers work - for anyone reading this comment, check out other answers too. For me, [answer about runtime configuration templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64125043/365237) was a life saver.

Answer (score 8):

If Maven is used project specific environment variables can be configured under ***File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Maven->Runner***
These are reused then in any Maven configuration.

The same mechanism to set the environment variables might also work with different runners.

Comment: this worked for me because I didn't want to pollute my system environment with variables that I'll only be using for one project

Comment: This will only work for maven executions (via IDE) - if you run code directly via IDE, you need something else.

Comment: This didn't work for me, until I put it in the Spring Boot Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: @Servietsky: Has the Spring Run/Debug configuration any relationship to Maven? As the answer is referring to Maven I'm wondering what is the expectation when a different runner is used. If the IntelliJ runner has a similar UI for different runners what works for the Maven set-up might also be beneficial for other runners. If this is the case I would add this note.

Comment: My project uses Maven and, as far as I know, the command `mvn spring-boot:run` is used to start a Maven based spring project. I wanted to mention that using the global (Runner) Maven environment variables have not been working for me on Spring. But maybe the `Spring Boot` configuration template uses other mechanisms I don't know of and it would probably work using Maven `spring-boot:run` directly.

Answer (score 8):

I tried various things listed above, and adding the environment variables to the terminal configuration and the Maven build tools worked in some contexts but not others. Then I finally found the place in IntelliJ that *actually* works for runtime processes. Because why just have one environment variable configuration screen when you can have several and make all but one of them wrong? ^_^

If you edit the *template* from which your run configurations are created, and add the environment variables *to the template*, then they should be included in every subsequent run configuration that started with that template.

This is especially useful for the JUnit template, since it will mean that all your custom environment variables will be loaded for unit tests, regardless of the scope from which they're executed (single method, whole test class, whole module). But in general, if you edit the templates first, then any run configuration you create thereafter will inherit your environment variables from the template.

From the top menu: **Run** → **Edit Configurations...** → expand **Templates** tree → *(choose a template)* → **Environment variables:** → *(enter a semicolon-delimited key-value pair list OR use the input widget)*

For the auto-generated JUnit configurations, you should blow away any existing ones, and let IntelliJ recreate new ones as you go; each of these will use the updated JUnit template with your environment variables.

Comment: This is good but still you need to modify several templates. And keeping the min sync is also crap.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, that IntelliJ does not "see" the environment variables that are set in .bashrc (Also to be found in CrazyCoders answer). The easiest way to enable IntelliJ to import those variables is to start it from bash e.g. by typing intellij-idea-community.

Comment: Running on RHEL 7.x and this was the issue. Gnome doesn't run the applications from within a bash shell, so starting the IDE from the menu caused this issue.

Answer (score 3):

For macOs try adding  `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties`

```
...
apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
apple.awt.fullscreencapturealldisplays=false
idea.jre.check=true
SOME_VAR=some value
```

Comment: Those are JVM system properties, not environment variables, AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

As no other answer mentioned it here,

Add your environment variable to **/etc/environment** , then log out and log in again. IntelliJ will definitely pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

I found another tricky solution :)
At least for Linux users...

Just create some shell script like *idea.sh* in any suitable location with this content.

```
#!/bin/bash
export YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE=some value
cd ~/path_to_your_idea_folder/bin
bash ./idea.sh
```

Make this script executable and run it.
This script will always run your IDE with predefined env variables.

Answer (score 1):

1. Got to `Open 'Edit Run/Debug configurations' dialogs`
   [image]
2. Go to `Modify options`
   [image]
3. Select `Environment variables`
   [image]
4. New box appears for `Environment variables` below `Active profiles`
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

@Dávid Leblay's answer does the trick. Just expanding on it here as I do not have enough rep to comment...

I'm on Linux Mint, and finding the location to my IntelliJ .desktop entry was tricky. Want to share the steps in case anyone else comes across this:

Use this command to properly identify the filename of your IntelliJ desktop entry:
`sed -n '/pinned-apps.*{/,/}/p' ~/.cinnamon/configs/grouped-window-list@cinnamon.org/*.json`

Mine ended up being "jetbrains-idea.desktop"

With the file name, you need the full path so that you can edit the entry. Find the path via this command: `find / -name '*.desktop'` -- (Including this because I went to `.local/share/applications/` as @sherminator35 noted for Ubuntu and my entry was not there)

Replace the * with your filename, e.g. `find / -name 'jetbrains-idea.desktop'`

With the path, edit the entry as @Dávid Leblay noted with vi or vim: `vim /path/to/entry/jetbrains-idea.desktop`

With that, IntelliJ should now properly pick up your env variables without having to edit the run config.

Resources that helped me:

- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=375712
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/117341/how-can-i-find-desktop-files

Answer (score 0):

**Where to create environment variable**

> IntelliJ IDE >  Edit Configuration > Environment Variables (Right button) > enter "key" and "value" (**Creates configuration**)

**How to use in JAVA**

> `System.getenv("key")` to retrieve env value

**How to create multiple environment**

> create multiple configurations :)