# How do I set environment variables on Mac OS with gradle and java9 in Intellij?

Tags: java, macos, gradle, intellij-idea

I have intellij 2017.3  gradle and java-9.

For example setting the PATH variable.

None of the following work.

- setting via the build dialog
- $PATH changes made in .profile OR
- OR /etc/paths OR
- /etc/launchd.conf

I'd expect the build dialog to work and setting within /etc/paths.

None of these options are working, and within the code the path variable is the default. e.g. without /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Please, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836696/2457251 It's a little more generic than your specific question and maybe it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was logged as a bug by JetBrains. The workaround is to use java-8 as the jvm for gradle. [IDEA-188768](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188768)