# Spring boot - Get enviromental variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

I have to get a enviromental variable and I can't inject.

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Client {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${BASE_URL}")
    private String baseUrl;

    public List<Car> getAllCars(){
        ResponseEntity<List<Car>> res = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl.concat("/car"),HttpMethod.GET,null, 
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Car>>() {});
        return res.getBody();
    }
}
```

I am not capable of inject basUrl that I have in the env.

Could some tell how I can do it?

I read the following pages and I am very beginner because I can't understan anything.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

Also I have tried with

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

Always the result is null.

Comment: What does your properties file look like? Is it definitely on the classpath?

Comment: Usally environment properties aren't uppercase. Maybe you just used the wrong key

Comment: I have used both @Value("${base.url}") and @Value("${BASE_URL}") and allways the same.

Comment: You sure that BASE_URL env variable is set in the same context where you run your application?
Can you clarify how do you set your environment variable?

Comment: I have made export BASE_URL=.... and it is present inwhen get those variables.

Comment: And when you export BASE_URL you invoke Java from the same shell?

Comment: No,  I am running java in the IDE.

Comment: How about setting the environment variable in IDE via run configuration?

Your exported variable is not visible outside the shell it's defined in and its children.

Comment: build it and run it as jar file @FranciscoJimenez

Comment: mvn clean test is working. thanks now I have to know ow set env proerties in Intellij.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696203/intellij-idea-global-environment-variable-configuration?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['BASE_URL']}")
```

Comment: Sorry I don't want to use application.proeries I need to get from the environmental variables.

Comment: in that case please try
    @Value("#{systemProperties['BASE_URL']}")