# How to set Intellij Scala REPL environment variables?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

When invoking the Scala REPL in intellij (Tools --> Scala REPL), **how can environment variables be manipulated for the REPL session**?

After launching the REPL a run configuration is created, but there is no environment variable window:

[image]

There is a [similar stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696203/intellij-idea-global-environment-variable-configuration) which deals with invoking a Scala application.  However, this question is not for a Scala application that has a `main`, rather this question deals with launching a REPL to test code on my classpath.

Comment: Feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=SCL.