# Definitive answer on where to put environment variables so IntelliJ IDEA will pick them up?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, environment-variables

Using IntelliJ IDEA (v2019.1.2 Ultimate on Manjaro Linux), I need to be able to "inject" some environment variables into the IDE on startup. For instance, all of my projects need to know the host name of the MYSQL server to use, e.g. `MYSQL_HOST`. **I have exported this and other variables in `/etc/bash.bashrc` as well as `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` but IDEA does not seem to pick up these variables from any of those locations even after logging out / rebooting.**

I am *not* interested in setting these environment variables for each and every project / run configuration manually. I need to set them once, globally, and have them apply everywhere.

However, to illustrate what I mean, IDEA does list the "system" environment variables that it has loaded in the *Run/Debug Configuration > Environment Variables* window:

[image: Environment Variables]

My specific env vars are not listed here, and I'm not sure from whence the listed vars came.

**Where should I enter environment variables so they will be picked up by IntelliJ IDEA?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA global environment variable configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45696203/608639), [Use Environment Variables in IntelliJ IDEA Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43815802/608639)

Comment: I've tried that (placing them in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`) and they are still not exposed to IDEA even after logging out / rebooting.

Comment: Your X11 programs are typically started by your X window manager, which is typically started by xsession, which typically reads your ~/.xsessionrc, but who knows really how it works on your system.

Comment: @n.m. -- thanks, I'm running Manjaro with KDE Plasma FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked when I add the variable to `/etc/environment`. After new login to system (not just restarting IntelliJ) I finally found the variable listed at system environment variables table in my run configurations.

*My IntelliJ IDEA version: 2022.2.2 (Ultimate Edition). My OS: Debian 11.4 (bullseye).*

Comment: Agreed. This is where I ended up putting them as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Linux the solution was to adjust the Intellij starter from:

```
/home/..path../idea/bin/idea.sh
```

to

```
/bin/bash -i -c "/home/..path../idea/bin/idea.sh" %f
```